# HTTP Request and response data Content-Type: application/encrypted-json;charset=UTF-8

Tags: javascript, json, encryption, encoding, content-type

I found `HTTP POST request` in website the request body and the response body `encrypted`  and the `Content-Type:` = `application/encrypted-json;charset=UTF-8`

i don't understand what is this? it's first time to see `HTTP request` like this! so i tried to search on google about `HTTP json encryption` or `Content-Type: application/encrypted-json` and i searched in `stackoverflow`, but i couldn't find anything

**The request**

```
POST /api/login/v1/auth HTTP/1.1
Host: id.example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0
Accept: application/encrypted-json;charset=UTF-8
Accept-Language: en-US
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
X-BusinessSystem: example
X-Timezone: GMT+2
X-From-HT: false
Content-Type: application/encrypted-json;charset=UTF-8
X-Protocol-Version: 1.0
X-Key: Xb14CswCy5e8XQPLb8HG0JbPc4QxZw+3t877CxyHJNCPg5OJpHR7C2X2/a240JEHDGnb2cdMBR1huNHlpywFbCxKYp6N3axdymn5HcgfjmBQlHienlXFqTs1g+J0nukGSAjzKMy1YsYf9oceIyM17wiUcIGeLK9J250X1TSN1ss=
X-Session-Ticket: qWGUmMh1c6EwWhuVArLoxWYMSs6pEi4c341Fz3ANiKw=
Content-Length: 280
Cookie: pgv_pvid=9688842132; __qc_wId=663
Connection: close

vEsDAG4HIvLzuxqJlppxeAUeURzkuA0VclgnhAglRHF/xQ0lJ7rReK2BR264OzOONgY/lGHtcWXt7AAqxFplzqI7kocCghJsR/nQtqRjn4ee6LwbBVaSZOQpWPpnuXifU8iTyCe3Akb32DESTHuZHN4S0cEDg8xYFkf/8ZlTLkTDcfbit0BtpDovEGIa9RM7Q7E12Bm/lMbohwdKCfvHCzxOwkuWpthOOp3ycdVIPeDRcryrczSnqu29o32PdCKrVSsoNQbTUfR4yzgoQPb9Fg==
```

**The response:**

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 23 Jun 2020 19:24:26 GMT
Content-Type: application/encrypted-json;charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 108
Connection: close
Server: nginx
X-Frame-Options: ALLOW-FROM https://id.example.com
X-Session-Ticket: qWGUmMh1c6EwWhuVArLoxWYMSs6pEi4c341Fz3ANiKw=
X-Gateway-Host: a499fa989cb43158986efe1417998cec3f49ef0cb03627023ff6a5beac0b05908b28c318e96f6dfe6387f4617d46734f
X-Backend-Host: 0162:18090

6iPusB8aZSx5Bf8PHHlWLg4Ui0FtF/q9zCbDz2W1M7AGj1k/CSN2zrRYZTp7Z+5lwjpRfYMuWrskAx9vgKHH6VS+Ma/vccl1X0+Ki2IRFxA=
```

**I tried to read the js files, i found something about the encryption, but i couldn't understand anything!**

```
("HttpEncrypt",this,function(){"use strict";var e=n("a2ec"),t=n("2324"),r=n("cd45"),i=n("b3a4"),o=n("509f").default,a=new o,s="",u=function(e){if(!(this instanceof u))return new u(e);e=e||{},this.rsaPublicKey=e.rsaPublicKey||"MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQDpgSW5VkZ6/xvh+wMXezrOokNdiupuvuMj4RVJy44byWDupl4H37z907A26RVdFzMeyLUQB4rsDIaXdxCODlljWW+/K96uF5MsDtOFUBw7VlOclIjcYTv/YDQEul8JoXoOuy1Yf3b5sbTpTuVTcl97tAuLJ8PoGe2K7N3B1eUQqQIDAQAB",this.protocolVersion=e.protocolVersion||"1.0",this.XSecurity=e.XSecurity||"",this.retryCount=0};u.prototype={getAesPrivateKey:function(){try{var e=this.getSessionAesKey()||""}catch(t){e=""}return e||this.createAESTicket()},getXKey:function(){return this.createAESTicket()},getSecurityTicket:function(){try{var e=window.sessionStorage.getItem("securitySessionTicket")||""}catch(t){e=""}return e},getSessionAesKey:function(){try{var e=window.sessionStorage.getItem("securitySessionTicket")||""}catch(n){e=""}var t="";if(e)try{t=window.sessionStorage.getItem("securitySessionAesTicket")||""}catch(n){}return t},createAESTicket:function(){if(s)return s;for(var e="ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz123456789",t=e.length,n="",r=0;r<16;r++)n+=e.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random()*t));return s=n,n},encrypt:function(n,o,s,u){return s=s||{},u=u||"AES",u&&"RSA"===u.toUpperCase()?(a.setPublicKey(o),a.encrypt(n)):(s.mode=s.mode||r,s.padding=s.padding||i,e.encrypt(t.parse(n),t.parse(o),s).toString())},decrypt:function(n,o,s,u){return s=s||{},u=u||"AES","RSA"===u.toUpperCase()?(a.setPublicKey(o),a.decrypt(n)):(s.mode=s.mode||r,s.padding=s.padding||i,e.decrypt(n,t.parse(o),s).toString(t))},encryptKey:function(n){if(!n)return"";var o=this.getAesPrivateKey();return e.encrypt(t.parse(n),t.parse(o),{mode:r,padding:i}).toString()},decryptKey:function(n){if(!n)return"";var o=this.getAesPrivateKey();return e.decrypt(n,t.parse(o),{mode:r,padding:i}).toString(t)},getEncryptAesKey:function(){var e=this.createAESTicket();return a.setPublicKey(this.rsaPublicKey),a.encrypt(e)},encryptBody:function(e){var t="";return t="object"==typeof e?JSON.stringify(e):e,this.encryptKey(t)},encryptHeader:function(e,t){if(e&&e.setRequestHeader){var n=this.getEncryptAesKey(),r=this.getSecurityTicket(),i=this.getSessionAesKey();try{e.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/encrypted-json;charset=UTF-8")}catch(o){e.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/encrypted-json;charset=UTF-8")}try{e.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/encrypted-json;charset=UTF-8")}catch(o){e.setRequestHeader("Accept","application/encrypted-json;charset=UTF-8")}if("2.0"===this.protocolVersion){try{e.setRequestHeader("X-Protocol-Ver","1.0")}catch(o){e.setRequestHeader("X-Protocol-Ver",encodeURI("1.0"))}try{e.setRequestHeader("X-Protocol",encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({key:n,sessionTicket:r&&i?r:""})))}catch(o){e.setRequestHeader("X-Protocol",encodeURIComponent(JSON.stringify({key:n,sessionTicket:r&&i?r:""})))}}else{try{e.setRequestHeader("X-Protocol-Version",this.protocolVersion)}catch(o){e.setRequestHeader("X-Protocol-Version",encodeURI(this.protocolVersion))}try{e.setRequestHeader("X-Key",n)}catch(o){e.setRequestHeader("X-Key",encodeURI(n))}}try{r&&i&&e.setRequestHeader("X-Session-Ticket",r)}catch(o){r&&i&&e.setRequestHeader("X-Session-Ticket",encodeURI(r))}try{this.XSecurity&&e.setRequestHeader("X-Security",this.encryptKey(this.XSecurity))}catch(o){this.XSecurity&&e.setRequestHeader("X-Security",encodeURI(this.encryptKey(this.XSecurity)))}}},send:function(e,t,n,r,i,o){o=o||"post";var a=XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest:new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");for(var s in a.open(o,e,!0),n=n||{},t=t||{},n)if(n.hasOwnProperty(s)&&"Ext-User"!=s&&"X-OPPO-DeviceName"!=s){var u=n[s];if("X-Safety"===s){try{a.setRequestHeader("X-Safety",this.encryptKey(u))}catch(f){a.setRequestHeader("X-Safety",encodeURIComponent(this.encryptKey(u)))}continue}if("Content-Type"===s)continue;try{a.setRequestHeader(s,u)}catch(f){a.setRequestHeader(s,encodeURI(u))}}this.encryptHeader(a);var l=this.encryptBody(t),c=this;a.onreadystatechange=function(s){if(4==a.readyState)if(200==a.status){var u,l=a.responseText||"",d=a.getResponseHeader("x-session-ticket");if(d)try{window.sessionStorage.setItem("securitySessionTicket",d),window.sessionStorage.setItem("securitySessionAesTicket",c.getAesPrivateKey())}catch(h){}try{u=JSON.parse(c.decryptKey(l))}catch(f){u=c.decryptKey(l)}r&&r(u)}else if(222==a.status){if(c.retryCount<2){c.retryCount++;try{window.sessionStorage.removeItem("securitySessionTicket"),window.sessionStorage.removeItem("securitySessionAesTicket")}catch(h){}return c.send(e,t,n,r,i,o)}c.commomSend(e,t,n,r,i,o)}else i&&i()},a.send(l)},commomSend:function(e,t,n,r,i,o){o=o||"post";var a=XMLHttpRequest?new XMLHttpRequest:new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");for(var s in a.open(o,e,!0),n=n||{},t=t||{},n)if(n.hasOwnProperty(s)){var u=n[s];try{a.setRequestHeader(s,u)}catch(l){a.setRequestHeader(s,encodeURI(u))}}a.onreadystatechange=function(){if(4==a.readyState)if(200==a.status){var e,t=a.responseText||"";try{e=JSON.parse(t)}catch(l){e=t}r&&r(e)}else i&&i(a.status)},a.send(JSON.stringify(t))}};try{window&&(window.HttpEncrypt=u)}catch(l){}return u})},"35c6":function(e,t,n){"use strict";var r=n("3332"),i=n("79c0"),o=n("3673"),a=n("5ce4"),s=n("2be5"),u=n("45d2");function
```

**Can anyone please explain what is that?**

**and explain how to `decrypt` something like that?**

Thanks.